# Why is the [arraylist] tag only about Java?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

Why is the description for tag [arraylist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arraylist) only about the Java implementation?

Yes, most of the questions are about the Java version. But there are a lot of realizations in different languages. For, example [C# ArrayList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: There are no noteworthy languages tagged in [arraylist] other than [java].  The C# flavor was obsoleted by `List<T>` 9 years ago.  Even if it were then it still doesn't matter, every language has a [string].  Tag visitors know what it means.

Comment: @HansPassant [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309694/arraylist-vs-list-in-c-sharp) is highly viewed and has this tag. I'm sure users won't nitpick about it, but maybe it's better to edit the tag and make general.

Comment: Many terms in this industry are overloaded.  It's better to just stick with the well-known, widely-accepted ones.

Comment: Oops, that was 12 years ago.  Time flies.

Comment: @Hans ^ ... like a banana. :D Who said this?

Comment: Googling for arraylist I found 8 results on the first 3 pages that had nothing to do with Java(YMMV depending on what google has on you) that's quite significant and I think the tag should be made general. @HansPassant And [string] *is* general, why should [arraylist] not be?

Comment: @Oleg, I would found a political party with you if it would be possible here :-)

Comment: @user0042 - Nobody.  The correct quotation is "Time flies like an arrow.  Fruit flies like a banana".  The correct attribution of that is unclear.  https://quoteinvestigator.com/2010/05/04/time-flies-arrow/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The simple/obvious answer is also the correct one: because [the person who wrote the tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6297186/2) ([Stephen C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139985/stephen-c)) is a Java expert. He interpreted the tag relative to his own expertise, just as we all tend to do, and he wrote about what he knows best, just as he should.

If we wait around for someone who has exhaustive knowledge of all languages, libraries, and tools to write a tag wiki, then we'll be waiting forever.

There's no particular reason why [arraylist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arraylist) should be limited to Java. There is certainly an ArrayList type in .NET, and possibly in other languages/frameworks that I am not familiar with, too.

While what Hans Passant observes is absolutely true—the ArrayList class is largely obsolete in the .NET world, having been superseded by the introduction of generic types in version 2—deprecated or not, the class *does* still exist, so there are still valid uses of the tag. Not to mention old questions, like [the one Maroun Maroun pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309694/arraylist-vs-list-in-c-sharp), that use the tag.

If you are familiar with one or more of these other languages/frameworks where ArrayList is found, then go ahead and revise the tag wiki to make it more general. That's why wikis are collaboratively edited.

Comment: Agreed ................................

Comment: If a person can ot reasonably be an expert in this tag (since it encompasses too many languages / frameworks), then what purpose does this tag have? If you can't be an expert in it, the tag shouldn't exist and should be changed to [java-arraylist], [c#-arraylist] etc.

Comment: Looks like Stephen C is an expert in the tag, @Polygnome, for whatever that actually means. No one knows *everything* about a tag. Having a bunch of [java-arraylist], [c#-arraylist], etc. tags is utterly pointless. The disambiguation is already provided by the language tag. It is easy to filter accordingly.

Comment: Maybe I'm not up-to-date on current meta, but shouldn't tags be usable on their own? Otherwise, if they are only sensible in conjunction with other tags, they are meta-tags, which are discouraged. Shouldn#t one criterion for a tag be that one can follow that tag, and only get questions that are reasonably scoped? Someone familiar with arraylists in java might have no clue about them in C#, and might not be able to answers such a question. therefore, he could not follow he [arraylist] tag witut getting questions he knows nothing about. in that case, the tag is rather pointless.

Comment: That has never been the rule, although it is a common misunderstanding of the term "meta tag". What it *actually* means is a tag that describes the *type* or *nature* of the question, instead of its *content*. The classic example is a [homework] tag, or [beginner]. Consider that have an [assembly] tag, but there are lots of different assembly languages. Do we really need a separate tag for each of them? No, not really. [assembly]+[x86] or [assembly]+[mips] work just fine. It is neither sensible nor practical to expect that questions have only one tag. If a language tag is missing, add it. @pol

Comment: "That has never been the rule" [citation-needed] "Tags are a means of **connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer** by sorting questions into **specific, well-defined categories**"

Answer (score 10):

I just went ahead and made the tag wiki somewhat less Java-centric by adding some prologue text, by moving the preexisting text under a new language / platform-specific heading, and by adding another heading for the .NET version of the identically-named data type.

If anyone else feels this was a bad idea or can be improved further, please edit away. :-)